# Turning point of equation

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

Using differentiation, find the turning points of
$$
(x^{2}+y^{2}-x)^2=x^{2}+y^{2}
$$

Thanks!

Comment: Try finding $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and equate it to $0.$ A better question to ask yourself is as why that gets you the 'turning point'.

Comment: @lebesgue 
the problem with that is that it gives me 
$$
(2x-1)(x^{2}+y^{2}-x)=x
$$

and substitution gives me 
$$
4x^{3}(x-1) + 4y^{2}(x^{2}-x+1) = 0 
$$
which doesn't seem solvable...?

Comment: Try polar coordinates.

Comment: Between the equations $(2x-1)(x^2+y^2-x) = x$ and $(x^2+y^2-x)^2=x^2+y^2$ you should be able to eliminate $y$ and obtain an equation in $x$ alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
\begin{equation}
(x^{2}+y^{2}-x)^2=x^{2}+y^{2}\tag1\label{eq:1}
\end{equation}
Differentiate both sides and put $y'=0$.

\begin{align*}
&(x^{2}+y^{2}-x)^2=x^{2}+y^{2}\\
\implies &2(x^2+y^2-x)(2x+2yy'-1)=2x+2yy'\\
\implies &(x^2+y^2-x)(2x-1)=x\tag2\label{eq:2}
\end{align*}
Using \eqref{eq:2} in \eqref{eq:1}, we get,
\begin{align*}
\left(\dfrac{x}{2x-1}\right)^2=x^2+y^2\tag3\label{eq:3}
\end{align*}
Using \eqref{eq:3} back into \eqref{eq:2}, we get,
\begin{align*}
&\left(\dfrac{x}{2x-1}\right)^2-x=\dfrac{x}{2x-1}\\
\implies &\left(\dfrac x{2x-1}-\dfrac12\right)^2=x+\dfrac14\\
\implies &\dfrac{1}{4(2x-1)^2}=\dfrac{4x+1}{4}\\
\implies &(4x+1)(2x-1)^2=1\tag4\label{eq:4}
\end{align*}
Now, \eqref{eq:4} is a cubic equation with $0$ as one of the roots.